# Why is vdir still around?

Tags: ls, history

After installing Debian 8, I started poking around /bin (as I'm always wont to do), and I noticed that `ls` and `vdir` share, not only the same manpage (except for the `whatis` line), but the exact same compiled size. The only thing they don't have in common is the inode number (which seems inefficient, but that's tangential).

Is there any reason for this? What's the historical precedent?
Why would we want to have both?

I'd never ever heard of `vdir` before today, so it can't be immensely common, and it seems like it should be easy to simply have `vdir` be a script that calls `ls` with the correct arguments.

Comment: Did you do `info vdir`?

Comment: @mikeserv I hadn't thought to (the last time I read an `info` page was at least three years ago), but on running it I got "‘vdir’ is equivalent to ‘ls -l -b’; that is, by default files are listed in long format and special characters are represented by backslash escape sequences." Still doesn't explain the reasoning behind having it. In fact, that explanation appears to argue against having it, since it is functionally equivalent to an existing app, yet it's an additional `118280` bytes.

Comment: Sure it does. `ls -l -b` is ambiguous if `ls` doesn't understand the `-b` option. It might even return successfully if the file `-b` exists in the current directory. The command `vdir` is a self-contained command, though, and so if you are writing a GNU-dependent script which depends on that stuff, `vdir` is a more simple thing for which to test. That it is an extra 118k probably speaks more to a lazy packager tthan otherwise. coreutils can be compiled as a *single* binary - the lot of them.

Comment: Similar tool is `dir` - the equivalent to `ls -C -b`.

Comment: @mikeserv Although the usual solution for filenames beginning with `-` is to separate them from options via `--`. On the other hand, I didn't know coreutils could be a single binary. Cool...

Comment: On my Ubuntu 15.04, running `sha1sum /bin/ls /bin/vdir` yields different hashes, implying that they're not the same file.

Comment: @saiarcot895 True, but what does an actual non-linewise diff give? One important property of crypto hashes is that they cascade; a small change in input results in a large number of output bit flips. A fuzzy hash, OTOH...

Comment: Yeah. It's just a guess, and which is why it's not an answer. At some point somebody thought it was valuable enough to warrant a separate utility. Obviously it doesn't predate `ls`, of course, so I find it hard to sympathize with an historical argument.

Comment: Oh, and anyway, I wasn't suggesting that a scripter might intend to separate filenames from options and get a false negative, but rather that a scripter might design his/her code in such a way that it can survivably handle `vdir`'s absence to some degree of lack - by which I mean a script would need to test if `ls -l -b` worked at all as an *option* and *not* as a file failing a separate callable like `vdir`. And besides, GNU parsing is weird so `ls . -a` is just fine.

Comment: @mikeserv There's no way that any well-behaved utility would interpret an unrecognized option as an argument, so any `ls` implementation that did not recognize `-b` would produce an error, not a listing for the file `./-b`, if that option were given.

Comment: @saiarcot895 `cmp -l` is more useful than `sha*sum` for cases like this. Not much point bothering with hashes when you can just compare directly, and you get a complete list of the differences as a bonus, which the OP was interested in seeing. By the way, those byte-by-byte differences aren't many!

Comment: @Celada - yes, there are ways, though I don't recall mentioning anything about being well-behaved. But `cmp` *is* better.

Comment: @ParthianShot, the use of `--` to close off options is a GNUism, as I understand it. Our SunOS (and perhaps also Solaris) boxes balked at it ("Unknown option '-'" or such helpful message).

Answer (score 8):

Most likely, for historical reasons and/or backward compatibility.

It's part of the GNU core utilities package, so it'll be around until Richard Stallman et al feel it's necessary to purge it from existence.